# How to reset (delete) remembered passwords in TortoiseHg?

Tags: tortoisehg

I am on Ubuntu and would like to delete the remembered passwords for a repository.

How do I achieve this please?

Thnaks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be in one of the `hgrc` files that applies to the repository - either the global one at `/home/your-user/.hgrc` or the repo-specific one at `/path/to/hg/repository/.hg/hgrc`.